# How to have a pptx convert to a pdf & how to fix opening problem?

Tags: python, pdf, request, upload, powerpoint

I am trying to make it so that a user can uload a pptx file and it will download the same file but as a pdf.

I already have code that makes the website and downloads the pptx as a pdf, but I cant open the file. I get "Failed to load PDF document." Below is the code I already have. I also used "pip install flask python-pptx reportlab" as one of my installations. I am running the code by entering python3 main.py into the terminal.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, send_file
from pptx import Presentation
from io import BytesIO

app = Flask(__name__)

def pptx_to_pdf(input_path, output_path):
    presentation = Presentation(input_path)
    output_stream = BytesIO()
    presentation.save(output_stream)
    output_stream.seek(0)
    with open(output_path, "wb") as f:
        f.write(output_stream.read())

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def convert_pptx_to_pdf():
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "pptx_file" not in request.files:
            return "No file part"
        
        pptx_file = request.files["pptx_file" or "docx_file"]
        if pptx_file.filename == "":
            return "No selected file"
        
        if pptx_file:
            file_name = pptx_file.filename
            input_path = os.path.join("/Users/veeraanand/Downloads", file_name)
            pptx_file.save(input_path)

            pdf_file_name = file_name.split(".")[0] + ".pdf"
            output_path = os.path.join("/Users/veeraanand/Downloads", pdf_file_name)

            pptx_to_pdf(input_path, output_path)

            return send_file(output_path, as_attachment=True)

    return '''
        <!doctype html>
        <title>PPTX to PDF Converter</title>
        <h1>Upload a PPTX file</h1>
        <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="pptx_file">
            <input type="submit" value="Convert and Download PDF">
        </form>
    '''

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```